# Overwrite pre-existing .mp3 file in Python using gtts

Tags: python, audio

I have a constraint with my syntax. I just tried `python` some time ago and I started it from AI. I make a bot like Jarvis to help me like opening google or youtube. From the tutorial available in [Pythonspot.com](https://pythonspot.com/personal-assistant-jarvis-in-python/) it shows for **Ubuntu** tutorial but I use **Windows**. And there are some tools or plugins that do not work in windows is `mpg321`. I have found a replacement with `mixer.music` to play the sound of the AI. This works but I have constraints on the second sound, ie i make the first sound with `audio.mp3` and it works then when my second voice uses the same filename ie `audio.mp3` and i have constraints like this

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "D:\@AI Projects\Jarvis\Jarvis.py", line 71, in 
>       jarvis(data)
>   File "D:\@AI Projects\Jarvis\Jarvis.py", line 53, in jarvis speak(ctime())
>   File "D:\@AI Projects\Jarvis\Jarvis.py", line 17, in speak tts.save("audio.mp3")
>   File "C:\Users\inialdan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\gtts\tts.py",
>   line 110, in save
>       with open(savefile, 'wb') as f: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'audio.mp3'

This is my code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# Requires PyAudio and PySpeech.

import speech_recognition as sr
from time import ctime
import time
import os
import subprocess
from gtts import gTTS
from pygame import mixer 



def speak(audioString):
    print(audioString)
    tts = gTTS(text=audioString, lang='en')
    tts.save("audio.mp3")
    mixer.init()
    mixer.music.load('D:/@AI Projects/Jarvis/audio.mp3')
    mixer.music.play()

def recordAudio():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Try to say something!")
        audio = r.listen(source)

    data = ""

    try:
        data = r.recognize_google(audio)
        print("You said : " + data)
    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        print("I'm Sorry, i couldn't understand what you mean ...")
    except sr.RequestError as e:
        print("Could not request results from Google Speech Recognition service; {0}".format(e))

    return data

def jarvis(data):

    CHROME = os.path.join('C:\\', 'Program Files (x86)', 'Google', 'Chrome', 'Application', 'chrome.exe')

    if "jarvis" in data:
        speak("Yes, sir ?")
    if "what is your name" in data:
        speak("You can call me, Jarvis")
    if "where do you leave" in data:
        speak("In your heart.")
    if "how are you" in data:
        speak("I am fine")
    if "what time is it" in data:
        speak(ctime())
    if "where is" in data:
        data = data.split(" ")
        location = data[2]
        speak("Hold on Aldan, I will show you where " + location + " is.")
        os.system('taskkill /im chrome.exe')
        subprocess.call([CHROME, "https://www.google.nl/maps/place/" + location + "/&amp;"])
    if "open" in data:
        data = data.split(" ")
        application = data[1]
        speak("Hold on Aldan, I will show you " + application)
        os.system('taskkill /im chrome.exe')
        subprocess.call([CHROME, "https://www." + application + ".com"])

time.sleep(2)
speak("Hi Aldan, How may I assist you?")
while 1:
    data = recordAudio()
    jarvis(data)
```

I have tried it with os.remove (); to remove the audio.mp3 and rewrite it. but still failed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have modified Speak method with the help of TemporaryFile.
[Click on the icon to check the Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpxU2.png)

```html
from googletrans import Translator
import pygame, time
import tempfile
from gtts import gTTS
from pygame import mixer
from tempfile import TemporaryFile

def speak(text, lang='en'):
    """Text to speech. For funp."""
    try:
        translator = Translator()
        tts = gTTS(text=translator.translate(text, dest=lang).text, lang=lang)
        mixer.init()
        sf = TemporaryFile()
        tts.write_to_fp(sf)
        sf.seek(0)
        mixer.music.load(sf)
        mixer.music.play()
    except Exception:
        raise
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a second def that removes the filename and run that command after your  speak()

```
def complete():
os.remove('audio.mp3')
speak("blah blah")
complete()
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this, it worked. You may have to guess the length of the sound. For mine, 2 sec is long enough.

```
    voice = gtts.gTTS(item)
    voice.save("temp.mp3")
    sound = SoundLoader.load("temp.mp3")
    sound.play()
    time.sleep(2)
    sound.stop()
    os.remove("temp.mp3")
```